# Format for writing a JSON log file?

Tags: json, logging, syntax, standards

Are there any format standards for writing and parsing `JSON` log files?

The problem I see is that you can't have a "pure" `JSON` log file since you need matching brackets and trailing commas are forbidden. So while the following may be written by an application, it can't be parsed by standard `JSON parsers:`

```
[{date:'2012-01-01 02:00:01', severity:"ERROR", msg:"Foo failed"},
{date:'2012-01-01 02:04:02', severity:"INFO", msg:"Bar was successful"},
{date:'2012-01-01 02:10:12', severity:"DEBUG", msg:"Baz was notified"},
```

So you must have some conventions on how to structure your log files in a way that a parser can process them. The easiest thing would be "one log message object per line, newlines in string values are escaped". Are there any existing standards and tools?

Comment: You can start the file with `[` and complete it with `{}]`. But, as some of the answers pointed out, json is not a "streamable" format.

Comment: **See also:** https://github.com/michaeltandy/log4j-json

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're not going to write a single JSON object per FILE, you're going to write a JSON object per LINE. Each line can then be parsed individually. You don't need to worry about trailing commas and have the whole set of objects enclosed by brackets, etc. See http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/03/28/service-logging-in-json-with-bunyan/ for a more detailed explanation of what this can look like.

Also check out Fluentd http://fluentd.org/ for a neat toolset to work with.

Edit: this format is now called JSONLines or `jsonl` as pointed out by @Mnebuerquo below - see http://jsonlines.org/

Comment: But writing JSON objects per line, without commas, and without enclosing brackets, **IS NOT JSON** anymore. You've created something else, something that no JSON interpreter will ever understand. Something that should not be called JSON.

Comment: As I said, the JSON is to be interpreted on a per-line basis. I'm not suggesting that you slurp the entire log file as one giant JSON blob, that would get way to big and bring most JSON interpreters to their knees since they'd have to create a bunch of objects for that. Instead, parse it out per line instead and then you can have perfectly valid JSON on every line of the file. So what if the entire file isn't valid JSON as one whole big object? You wouldn't want that, anyway.

Comment: That log format is called JSON-lines by various logging apps. Logstash for example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-json_lines.html

Answer (score 0):

gem `log_formatter` is the ruby choice, as the formatter group, now support json formatter for ruby and log4r.

simple to get stated for ruby.

```
gem 'log_formatter'

require 'log_formatter'
require 'log_formatter/ruby_json_formatter'

logger.debug({data: "test data", author: 'chad'})
```

result

```
{
  "source": "examples",
  "data": "test data",
  "author": "chad",
  "log_level": "DEBUG",
  "log_type": null,
  "log_app": "app",
  "log_timestamp": "2016-08-25T15:34:25+08:00"
}
```

for log4r:

```
require 'log4r'
require 'log_formatter'
require 'log_formatter/log4r_json_formatter'

logger = Log4r::Logger.new('Log4RTest')
outputter = Log4r::StdoutOutputter.new(
  "console",
  :formatter => Log4r::JSONFormatter::Base.new
)
logger.add(outputter)

logger.debug( {data: "test data", author: 'chad'} )
```

Advance usage: [README](https://github.com/chadlwm/log_formatter)

Full Example Code: [examples](https://github.com/chadlwm/log_formatter/tree/master/examples)